# What is the general method for generating the possible combinations in a partition of $N$ sets?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, with two sets we have a partition of size $3$: $A \setminus B$, $B \setminus A$, and $A \setminus B$.

With three sets we have a partition of size $7$: $A \cap B \cap C$, $A \cap (B \setminus C)$, etc., and $A \setminus (B \cup C)$, etc.

For $N$ sets, what is the partition size, and how can I generate the set of partition members?

Comment: What do you mean by partition? If I have sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n$, do you mean how you express the space of these sets using disjoint sets? I think you would have a “partition” for every subset of indices {1, ..., n} of sets. For example, the subset $2, 5, 6$ would repesent elements in $A_2 \cap A_5 \cap A_6 - (\text{every other set})$.  This would give $2^n - 1$ partitions, where the $-1$ is to discount the empty set.

Comment: In your first example, you have $A \setminus B$ twice. Presumably one of them should be $A \cap B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $A_1, \dots, A_n$, a given member will either belong to $A_i$ or not, for each $1 \le i \le n$. This means that your "partition members" will look like

$$
\require{enclose}
A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n\\
A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap \overline A_n\\
\vdots\\
\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\overline A_1 \cap \overline A_2 \cap \cdots \cap \overline A_n}
$$

where $\overline A_i$ is the complement of $A_i$. The list consists of all $2^n - 1$ possible combinations of the $A_i$ and their complements (except for the last one, which is discounted, as @gowrath says in the comments, for not including any of the $A_i$).